# Confusion in parameter estimation of conditional random field

Tags: gradient-descent, conditional-random-field

I have a certain confusion while taking the derivative of the log likelihood of the conditional random field. As given in this paper http://people.cs.umass.edu/~mccallum/papers/crf-tutorial.pdf

I mean while calculating the gradient with respect to a parameter
$$
\lambda_k
$$

the derivate of the logZ term bring this term. 
$$
p(y,y'|x^{(i)})
$$

I am not sure how this term appeared while calculating the gradient. It is equation 1.22 of page 12 in the paper http://people.cs.umass.edu/~mccallum/papers/crf-tutorial.pdf

Can anyone please provide some insights?

Answer (score 1):

I agree it's puzling; an insight comes from another McCallum-Sutton paper:

> In the likelihood, inference is needed to compute the partition
>   function Z(x(i)), which is a sum over all possible labellings. In the
>   derivatives, inference is required to compute the marginal
>   distributions p(y, y' | x(i)).

Remember that Z(x) is defined as a sum over Y of functions of the form f(y, y', x), so its derivative "brings out again" the y, y' arguments.